# How to use a value as a keyword to call a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

Hey I want to use the value as a keyword of a const variable along with "this".

```
const northAmerica = "Welcome to north america";

private __onChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>, item: IDropdownOption): void => {
this.setState({ mco: this.`${item.key}` });  };
```

Whenever I get the item.key = "northAmerica" I want to assign the mco to const northAmerica. Is there any way to do it.I tried using $`{item.key}` but getting an error.

```
error:Identifier expected.
```

Comment: So you want to be there this.northAmerica eventually?

Comment: Try with eval()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
this[`${item.key}`]
```

Example:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'HELLO';
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this['a']);
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.print();
```

Comment: In what is different from `this[item.key]` ?

Comment: @6502 Ermm that would pretty much be the same, but I just copied as-is from his code.

Comment: @6502 @huytc There would be a difference. `\`${item.key}\`` will always be a string whereas `item.key` might evaluate as a number so `this[item.key]` would access the field at index `item.key` instead of the value with key of `item.key`.

Comment: @Nikaoto Yes, I get that. But since OP wants to pass in a variable name, the case where `item.key` is not a string is less likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
this.setState({ mco: this[item.key] });
```

or

```
this.setState({ mco: this[`${item.key}`] });
```